# Remove gradient on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Is there a way to remove the gradient on the navigationBar on UINavigationController in iOS6.

I have tried making a subclass of UINavigationController then set the navigationBar of it to the subclass though it says that the navigationBar is a readOnly variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `-[setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics]` , you can use a single pixel image with the color of your choice.

but, to set the class of the navBar of your UINavController use `-[ initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:]` , 
or, just set it on the navigationBar object on the storyboard or nib if your using one.

Answer (score 2):

In storyboard I did remove gradient by unchecking `Translucent` property of `UINavigationBar` inside `UINavigationController`.

[image]

Comment: In swift 4 `viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`